# How to rightly add resources in Qt application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qurl, qresource

I am trying to deploy windows application in Qt, so I change mode to release, but when I execute it, all it writes is

```
file::/qml/Main.qml: File is empty
```

I have already tried multiple times to rework **resources.qrc**, but with no success.

**resources.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/Pages/DetailPage.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Pages/IntroPage.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Pages/LibaryPage.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Pages/Page.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Pages/PageView.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Controls/ControlSlider.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Models/CityModel.qml</file>
        <file>images/heatmapicon.png</file>
        <file>qml/Main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I have tried to copy qml and images folder (they are in same folder as **main.cpp** and **resources.qrc**), but no success too.

This is how I set main source for `QQuickView` :

```
view_->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QStringLiteral(":/qml/Main.qml")));
```

In debug mode, there is no problem and everything start as it should.

How can I change resource/code to make it work?

Thanks for your help!

//EDIT:

I have manage to solve it with `view_>setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Main.qml")));`

Comment: Just to make sure, are you referring to qrc file in your project file? It should be e.g.`RESOURCES += resources.qrc`? Also, try to run clean/qmake/rebuild sequence, sometimes Qt Creator tries to be too smart about when to actually process resource files which results to ignoring the changes.

Comment: @shrpq Yes, I am reffering and I already rebuilt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `QUrl::fromLocalFile()`, that function is indicating that you are looking for a local file, but the paths handled by a .qrc are virtual.

Use:

```
view_->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Main.qml")));
```

Comment: All it wrote was `path.../bin/release/: File is empty`.
I have manage to solve it with `view_->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Main.qml")));`

Comment: @Brykyz 
that matches my answer.

Comment: I thought it would match too (at least by my knowledge about qt resources), but no, without `qrc:` (instead of `:`) before path it doesn't work